# Reinterpret Array of Bytes into Managed Struct Using Fixed Buffers

Tags: c#, byte, buffer, reinterpret-cast

I'm looking to reinterpret_cast an array of bytes into a C# struct. I've read several other answers to the problem, most have been about how to implement reinterpret cast. I've settled on a means to reinterpret cast, but I'm getting single characters instead of arrays of characters during my casting.

For instance, I have the following object:

```
    public unsafe struct Establish503
    {
        public static Establish503 ReinterpretCast(byte[] message)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(message, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            Establish503 theStruct = (Establish503)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
                typeof(Establish503));
            handle.Free();
            return theStruct;
        }

        public fixed char HMACSignature[32];
        public fixed char AccessKey[20];
        public fixed char TradingSystemName[30];
        public fixed char TradingSystemVersion[10];
        public fixed char TradingSystemVendor[10];
    }
```

For some reason instead of having an array of bytes, I have single characters where an array should be. Why is this so? Here is my Locals debug window:

[image]

As you can see, it is considering all fields as `char` and not `char[]` for some reason.

If this is not the proper approach, is there something else I should be looking at? I've been looking into `Span<T>`.

**EDIT:** After further discussions with the author of the selected answer, Oguz Ozgul, it was determined that marshalling would be the best approach. A follow up question is, how would I deal with a nested struct? The following is my current approach. As Oguz mentioned, for structs defined outside of a class, and which contain primitive types, it is okay to exclude the Marshal attributes. These structs can then be used as fields in another struct. I've tackled defining nested structs similar to how I'd define non-nested structs.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public struct OrderMassActionReport558
    {
        public const int templateId_ = 558;
        public const int blockSize_ = 103;

        public static OrderMassActionReport558 ReinterpretCast(byte[] message)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(message, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            OrderMassActionReport558 theStruct = (OrderMassActionReport558)
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 
                typeof(OrderMassActionReport558));
            handle.Free();
            return theStruct;
        }

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uInt32 seqNum;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
        public uInt64 uUID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
        private byte[] _senderID;
        public string senderID => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._senderID);
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
        public uInt64 partyDetailsListReqID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
        public uInt64 transactTime;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
        public uInt64 sendingTimeEpoch;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
        public uInt64 orderRequestID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
        public uInt64 massActionReportID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
        private byte[] _securityGroup;
        public string securityGroup => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._securityGroup);
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
        private byte[] _location;
        public string location => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._location);
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public Int32NULL securityID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public uInt16NULL delayDuration;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public MassActionResponse massActionResponse;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public ManualOrdIndReq manualOrderIndicator;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public MassActionScope massActionScope;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public uInt8 totalAffectedOrders;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public BooleanFlag lastFragment;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public uInt8NULL massActionRejectReason;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public uInt8NULL marketSegmentID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public MassCxlReqTyp massCancelRequestType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public SideNULL side;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public MassActionOrdTyp ordType;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public MassCancelTIF timeInForce;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public SplitMsg splitMsg;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public BooleanNULL liquidityFlag;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public BooleanFlag possRetransFlag;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
        public struct NoAffectedOrdersEntry
        {
            public const int blockSize_ = 32;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
            private byte[] _origCIOrdID;
            public string origCIOrdID => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this._origCIOrdID);
            public uInt64 AffectedOrderID;
            public uInt32 CxlQuantity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fixed buffer fields are handled as pointers so the debugger shows them as if they were `char*` fields: it shows the first character only. But non-void pointers are indexable so you can access all the characters, eg. `theStruct.HMACSignature[1]`, etc.

Comment: Dear @GyörgyKőszeg, as far as my knowledge goes, the char* pointers are displayed as \0 terminated strings by the debugger. When I run OP's code and break and see the struct in the memory window, I see that only the first bytes of each of the char* variables are set, the rest is set to zero. That's why the debugger shows only one character, because the char[] or char* contains only one.

Comment: Not by the C# debugger: it shows the pointers always as expandable tree nodes. When expanded, it shows the `ToString` value of the underlying type. For a `char*` it is a single character. If they were displayed as zero-terminated strings then the last item in the screenshot would be an empty string, not a single `\0` character (and see also the last column: it displays `char`, not a string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because only the first elements of your char arrays are set and the rest is zero (you can see this in the Memory window).

First of all, trying to fill the char array with raw binary data can cause undesired and unpredictable results, unless we can specify the exact charset. You can see on top of the struct that the CharSet is sete to Ansi, 1 bytes per character.

Then, instead of using fixed pointer char arrays, you can use strings but marshal them by value and with an exact size.

Please let me know if this helps:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct Establish503
    {
        public static Establish503 ReinterpretCast(byte[] message)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(message, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            Establish503 theStruct = (Establish503)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
                typeof(Establish503));
            handle.Free();
            return theStruct;
        }

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string HMACSignature;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        public string AccessKey;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 30)]
        public string TradingSystemName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string TradingSystemVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string TradingSystemVendor;
    }
```

UPDATE 1: The OP also asked an additional question in a comment below, so the answer is updated.

The OP wants to know what if another struct, which has an Int64 field, is embedded into the current one.

First, reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior#default-marshaling-for-value-types

So I added this new struct to the source code:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public struct Data
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]
        public long LongField;
    }
```

Then, embedded it in the current one:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct Establish503
    {
        public static Establish503 ReinterpretCast(byte[] message)
        {
            GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(message, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            Establish503 theStruct = (Establish503)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
                typeof(Establish503));
            handle.Free();
            return theStruct;
        }

        public Data DataStruct;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string HMACSignature;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        public string AccessKey;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 30)]
        public string TradingSystemName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string TradingSystemVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10)]
        public string TradingSystemVendor;
    }
```

And finally, marshaled it back from unmanaged memory:

```
        Establish503 establish503 = Establish503.ReinterpretCast(new byte[] { 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure where it says the char set is Ansi. In my Locals window, or in my code snippet? I see no "Ansi" in either.Thank God I read into what Pack=1 means. And for the record, this works beautifully.

Comment: Ansi is here, in the StructLayout attribute on top of the class in my answer: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]`

Comment: Also, how would I do this with a custom type? @OguzOzgul

Comment: Hi. We probably have a big time diff. It's 09:39 here :) What do you mean by custom types? Having a field of your custom class type instead of string?

Comment: Correct! For instance, if I create a struct called Data and I add a field `Data _myData` to `Establish503`. As it stands, what I've done is added marshalling to Data, which only contains primitive types, similar to how you've shown me for Establish503. For example, if `Data` contained an `Int64` I'd add `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8)]` above this field. I then added `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]` above Data _myData in Establish503. Is this the correct way of doing so?

Comment: Hi. For simple value types like Int64, you don't even have to specify a MarshalAs attribute unless you want to override the default marshaling behavior. Also for a struct, you don't have to tell the run-time that it is a struct, which it knows already. Bu to be on the safe side, declaring those attributes is the best. I am updating my answer to reflect what you are asking, and I think you already achieved success when tried for yourself.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk I realized something. When specifying the size const on strings, I think one byte is reserved for the terminating \0 character. So if the size const is 32, you get a string with maximum length 31. For your information.