# Byte[] from pointer without copy

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have a byte*, and I would like to turn that into a byte[]. Now I don't want to copy it, and I know the length of the byte*.

I could use `memcpy`, but I want to avoid copying the bytes from byte* into a new byte array.
Is there any way to do this? I'm open to ANY way, whether it uses P/Invoke, or unsafe code, whatever.
Thanks

EDIT:
What I'm doing is converting a UTF-8 byte* into another encoding format.
For example, the data I have stored is ALWAYS Utf-8, but I want to convert it into any other format.

I do this by doing this:

```
char[] chars = new char[size];
Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(utf8Array, 0, utf8Array.Length, chars, 0);

byte[] convertedBytes = someOtherEncoding.GetBytes(chars);
```

That's why I need the utf8Array. Also, GetChars have a pointer methods but that method internally copies bytes.

Answer (score 0):

No. .NET does not provide a mechanism to convert an unmanaged pointer directly into a managed array. The closest you can come is to create the managed array first, and then in an `unsafe` context, get a pointer for the data in the array and use that as your unmanaged array. However, your question is vague and it's not clear whether that would be an option for you.

That said, I am skeptical that there's a real-world requirement for this. You should explain *why* you think this is something you need to do. It seems likely you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Or maybe even no problem at all, i.e. this is a premature optimization. The fact is, text encoding/re-encoding scenarios are rarely a bottleneck in a program and not deserving of heroic efforts for optimization.

Yes, copying bytes is slower than not copying bytes. But copying bytes is a very fast operation on most modern architectures. It's way more work to do the actual encoding conversion itself.

It would probably be a good idea for you to post a new question that focuses on the original problem that led you to believe that the question you're asking here would be useful to have an answer to. In that new question, please be sure that you provide a good [minimal, complete, and verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make sure you also explain in detail what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and what *specifically* you need help with.

If your problem involves a performance concern, make sure that your code example demonstrates that performance concern correctly (i.e. is a well-designed benchmark). Also make sure that you explain what the performance goal is and why you believe that the goal is achievable and worth investing the effort in. I.e. why is the code you're asking about the actual bottleneck; the code example should illustrate this by showing the bottleneck in context.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Peter. However I will try looking just a bit more, and will mark this accepted if I cannot find a solution. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: If you haven't already seen this, you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713048/reinterpret-array-of-bytes-into-managed-struct-using-fixed-buffers. It's not exactly the same scenario as yours, but it might give you some idea for things to try (though the gist of the answer is pretty much the same...i.e., you can't literally do what you're asking). If you do happen to find something that solves your problem better than "no, you can't do that", feel free to post an answer to this question yourself and accept it so that it's clear your question has been solved.